# Using A Defined Range With SpecialCells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find nonempty cells in a defined range variable using `.SpecialCells`, if I use:

```
    Set aRange = Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(botRow, 5))
    Set tRange = aRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
```

`tRange` is Empty. However, if I use:

```
    Set tRange = Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(botRow, 5)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
```

`tRange` has what I want.

Why doesn't `.SpecialCells` work on a defined range variable?
Am I missing something?

Comment: you are using different arguments in your special cells

Comment: Are both of these variables declared as `Range`?

Comment: Both are declared as ranges, xlCellType corrected

Comment: I have done this before so i'm wondering if any cells in your range actually meet the criteria? i.e. when you set `aRange`, have you verified it has any cells that meet criteria `xlCellTypeConstants`?

Comment: They do, I have checked that. I can use the work around in the second code snippet, but am wondering why this happens.

Comment: I would qualify your range with a worksheet. If your range location is defined correct and has constants then unqualified ranges would be the likely issue

Comment: Yes, that worked: Set aRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(botRow, 5))

Comment: `ActiveSheet` on its own won't rectify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to qualify your objects (*`Ranges & Cells`*) with a worksheet:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Update

Dim aRange as Range, tRange as Range

Set aRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 5), ws.Cells(botRow, 5))
Set tRange = aRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `SpecialCells` with `xlCellTypeConstants`, add the second parameter too. This is a combination of the checkboxes you find in the Go To Special dialog. If you want all, do like this:

```
aRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlErrors + xlLogical + xlNumbers + xlTextValues)
```

This will work with both your versions.